# Clear all input text box vale at append time

Tags: javascript

What I want is that when I click on add more, append all text box with blank value add more function is properly working but at the time of appending input box append with value but I want to clear text box value.

```
 <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="topdivdata">
    <td> <input type="text" value="First Name"></td>
    <td> <input type="text" value="Last Name"></td>
    <td> <input type="text" value="Mobile Number"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td>
    <span class="btn btn-xs cic" id="addnewunit">
    <i class="icon-plus"></i>+ Add More</span>
    </td>   
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="addmoreunit"></tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>

    <script>
    unitcount=1;
     $('#addnewunit').click(function()
                {
                 var topdiv = $('.topdivdata').html();  
                 var refresdiv=topdiv;
            $('#addmoreunit').append('<tr>.'+refresdiv+'.<td class="removes1"><span class="btn btn-xs"><i class="icon-plus"></i>- Remove</span></td></tr>');    
    unitcount++;
        var value = $('.target').val();
                    $('.list').val(value);
                    $('.removes1').click(function()
                        {
                            $(this).parent().remove();
                        });
    });

    </script>
```

```html
 i want to when i click on add more append all text box with blank value add more function properly working but at append time input box upend with value but i want to clear text box value 
 <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="topdivdata">
    <td> <input type="text" value="First Name"></td>
    <td> <input type="text" value="Last Name"></td>
    <td> <input type="text" value="Mobile Number"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td>
    <span class="btn btn-xs cic" id="addnewunit">
    <i class="icon-plus"></i>+ Add More</span>
    </td>   
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="addmoreunit"></tbody>
    </table>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
    
    <script>
    unitcount=1;
     $('#addnewunit').click(function()
       {
        var topdiv = $('.topdivdata').html(); 
        var refresdiv=topdiv;
      $('#addmoreunit').append('<tr>.'+refresdiv+'.<td class="removes1"><span class="btn btn-xs"><i class="icon-plus"></i>- Remove</span></td></tr>'); 
    unitcount++;
     var value = $('.target').val();
        $('.list').val(value);
        $('.removes1').click(function()
         {
          $(this).parent().remove();
         });
    });
      
    </script>
```

Comment: What? Can you explain this clearer?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/r84mtxd3/

Comment: @RayonDabre answer is good.

Answer (score 0):

not understand your question, but you can do like these,

```
<table>
 <tbody>
    <tr class="topdivdata">
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="First Name">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="Last Name">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="Mobile Number">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td>
            <span class="btn btn-xs cic" id="addnewunit" style="cursor:Pointer;">
                <i class="icon-plus"></i>+ Add More
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody id="addmoreunit"></tbody>
</table>
```

and script is like,

```
 var unitcount = 1;
$('#addnewunit').click(function () {

    //Here i cloned your topDiv, so that i can add new inputs.
    var CloneTopDiv = $('.topdivdata').clone(true);
    CloneTopDiv.find(':input').attr('value', '');
    CloneTopDiv.attr('class', 'txtInput')
    CloneTopDiv = CloneTopDiv.html();
    var refresdiv = CloneTopDiv;
    $('#addmoreunit').append('<tr>.' + refresdiv + '.<td class="removes1"><span class="btn btn-xs" style="cursor:Pointer;"><i class="icon-plus"></i>- Remove</span></td></tr>');
    unitcount++;
    var value = $('.target').val();
    $('.list').val(value);

    //Code for Remove added row
    $('.removes1').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });

    //Clearing Code
    $('.txtInput').val('')

});
```

See solution at https://jsfiddle.net/eua98tqa/3/

Comment: in first tr all inputs value should not be clear only new append input box value should be blank